# Storage running out, can't get it back

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I'm looking for a solution to getting storage back on my phone because, as of yesterday, I seemed to lose almost 10GB of space.  I have a Galaxy s6 and I frequently connect it to my computer via the charger and transfer video files to and from both. After I'm done with the files, I delete them, getting my space back. But, yesterday a problem arose when I transferred video files TO my computer and deleted them from my phone. The space never cleared up and now I have (after much cleaning up with many apps) only a little over 1GB of space left. I need to get my 7-9 GB of space back and have done much research.

The *#9900# trick doesn't bring me to any options of deleting possible SysDump files and I'm not looking to root my phone. If there are any other ideas, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you rooted? Custom ROM? Custom recovery (TWRP, CWM, Philz)?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are really gone from the phone, your storage should reflect that. Try restarting the phone, Download a different file explorer and check the place where your files were. GO to settings/General/Storage/Internal Storage (i assume) and see how the looks look from there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is much cache or thumbnail cache. Try installing the app named 'CCleaner' by Piriform. It saves a lot of space for me.